# installing IPython with two versions of Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, ipython

Is it possible to have **IPython (0.12)** installed on the *same*
system with two different versions of Python (v 2.7 and 3.2)? Currently I have both versions of Python running happily  on my system.

I am using two machines, one with  **Windows 7 64-bit**, the other  **XP SP2 32-bit**, and both have **Python 2.7.2** and **3.2** installed. I have been using IPython with Python 2.7 w/o any problems for a while on both.

Now I would like to have 3.2 available too with IPython, but when I try to run the binary windows IPython installer I get this error toward the end of the install:

```
*** run_installscript: internal error 0xFFFFFFFF ***
```

and no shortcuts/entries into Start Menu etc are created.
(I ran the install as adminstrator under Win 7) I am running into the same problem with XP and Win 7.

After poking around the net and SO for a while I saw references for
getting [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files). Unfortunately, there's no version for Python 3.x
but it was suggested to use [distribute.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) instead which I ran and
installed. I am not sure how to proceed next. And I'm not even sure it
is possible to do this (though I think it is :)

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: There was a problem with `import readline` not working with Python 3.2.3, but I was able to fix it by downloading [pyreadline-2.0-dev1.win32.exe](https://launchpad.net/pyreadline/+download) which works with Python 3.2.3 .. the above problem remains unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know about windows but it works in Arch Linux.

Comment: You have two different version of Windows installed as well as Python?

Comment: @martineau No, sorry, I am trying to have this setup (iPython with Python 2.7 and 3.2) on two different machines, one running XP the other Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried running the binary installer after you installed `distribute`?

Comment: @ThomasK Yes (multiple times :-/ )  .. still end up with the same error message, and no entry in the start menu etc.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the installer, then. Sorry, Windows & Python 3 is the least-tested combination. You could try installing it with `easy_install ipython` or `pip install ipython`.

Comment: @ThomasK yes, I was trying to get up-to-date because sometimes my answers on [python] SO are off bkz I use 2.x. Could you elaborate on the `easy_install ipython` option? In my Python 3.2/Scripts directory there's `easy_install.exe/easy_install-3.2.exe` (and `-script.py` versions). Do I run the executables in that directory, or the python scripts? (I think I've tried both w/o luck, but at that point I was just trying things w/o knowing where I was going with it)

Comment: I'd try either of the `.exe` ones, but I don't know what's recommended on Windows. Alternatively, download the zipped source, unzip, and run `python3 setup.py install`

Comment: @ThomasK I figured out some sort of solution ... finally. Oof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here's my solution to get **IPython 0.12.1** to work with both **Python ver
2.7.x and 3.2.x** on the same system (ie. under **Windows 7** 64 bit and **XP** SP2 32 bit). It's not
perfect, but works, and hopefully will help others. Where I am showing directories they refer to XP (but should be adjusted accordingly for Windows 7)

**Steps for both:**

1. Install both versions of Python via the binary windows installer provided at
   [Python.org](http://Python.org)
2. Install this version of pyreadline [pyreadline-2.0-dev1.win32.exe](https://launchpad.net/pyreadline/+download) which works 
   for *both* versions of Python (I could not get the widely available version 1.7 to work with Python 3.2.x)
3. I am not sure if [distribute.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) is necessary, I'd skip it on the
   first try.
4. Download  [ipython-0.12.1.zip](http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.12.1/ipython-0.12.1.zip) file and extract it. Place it under your Programs directory and cd into it (I'll call this the `ipython_dir`) [I tried  the binary installer numerous times without success]

**For Python 3.2 (easier)**

In the `ipython_dir`:

```
c:\python32\pyton.exe setup.py install
```

will create  `ipython3.exe` in `c:\python32\Scripts` that can be used to
fire up iPython

**For Python 2.7 (a bit odd)**

The above method failed. However, it is possible to start IPython from the `ipython_dir` with

```
c:\python27\python.exe  ipython.py
```

I can't explain why this is so, but since I use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) I can hide
these two ways of starting IPython.

**Summary**:

To start IPython with v 2.7.x of Python:

```
c:\python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files..\ipython_dir\ipython.py"
```

To start IPython with v 3.2.x of Python:

```
c:\python32\Scripts\python3.exe
```

That was a lot of work and took most of the day, so I hope posting the steps above
will save someone else a lot of time (and help me remember what I have to do next time I struggle with this)

Thanks everyone for their suggestions.

*Addendum*: None of the above resulted in shortcuts or entries in the Start/Program Menus. Shortcuts can be created manually, or in my case aren't necessary since I'm using a special shell (Console2) to run IPython.

Comment: IIRC, you need distribute if you want the binary installer to make shortcuts in the start menu for IPython. I'm not sure why installing it didn't work for Python 2.7, that's certainly possible.

Comment: @ThomasK I thought so too, but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: If you've got time to test this sort of thing, it would be great to have some more hands making sure it works well on Windows. I think the first thing would be to get a clean machine (perhaps a VM) and see if we could replicate the sort of problems you had. If you're interested, drop us a line on the mailing list: http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-dev

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks for the suggestion of the VM, didn't even think of that .. duh! :) .. if I figure out something, I'll be sure to share. I really like the IPython environment, and I know I haven't even fully started to explore/exploit it .. I mostly use it as a simple shell.

Answer (score 1):

The first question in the iPython [FAQ](http://ipython.org/faq.html) titled "Running IPython against multiple versions of Python" may help.

Comment: thanks for the link, I'm not quite sure how to translate that to my Windows environment. I remember having problems with the initial installation too .. (I've seen a fair number of problem reports with Windows installs). I'm sure this would be easier under Linux (which seems much more flexible)

Comment: @Leveon: I think you just need to translate the path portion of `--prefix=$HOME/usr` to where the site-packages for each of the two Python interpreters are installed on your system (as well as the beginning interpreter invocations, of course).

Comment: I figured out some sort of solution ... finally. Oof.