# Python console in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, console, interpreter

I'm unable to run a python console inside Eclipse. I've downloaded Pydev, set up an interpreter and a PYTHONPATH and imported a project, a Django project. I set up the project as a Django one and then I tried right click on the project-->Django-->shell with Django environment.

I got the following error in the console:

```
Error starting server with host: 127.0.0.1, port: 1349, client_port: 1350
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <pyreadline.console.console.Console object at 0x026EA210>
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <pyreadline.console.console.Console object at 0x026EA210>
```

If I try to open a Windows shell and do the usual python manage.py shell all goes smooth so I guess I have some problem with the Eclipse configuration but I have no clue.

Thanks for your help

I figured it out the problem but I still have no solution. If I uninstall IPython the shell in Eclipse works correctly, of course I don't have IPython anymore though. If I reinstall IPython I lose all the functionality in my Eclipse Python shell while I have Python perfectly working in a Windows terminal. What Eclipse is doing???

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, this post help me:
[installing IPython with two versions of Python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787084/installing-ipython-with-two-versions-of-python-windows)
I have win7. I think that problem is pyreadline library. If I updated to pyreadline-2.0-dev1.win32.exe, it is OK. Can be downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyreadline

Comment: You gave me a clue about the 2 versions of IPython, in fact I had 2 of them but still, after I deleted one I have the same problem. I edited the question to explain the exact problem

Answer (score 1):

I found it!! You don't need to uninstall Python or any other things, it is a problem entirely of Eclipse. Go here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.5.0.2012040618\PySrc
```

or if you have PyDev in a different location just search for the file

```
pydev_ipython_console
```

In that folder make sure you only have one such file. For example in my case I had:

```
pydev_ipython_console (py)
pydev_ipython_console (pyc)
pydev_ipython_console_010 (py)
pydev_ipython_console_010 (pyc)
```

Just deleting the first 2 made the console working properly and even installing IPython to have it on a Windows terminal didn't cause any problem with the Eclipse console